# Passing namespace in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

We have an exercise about inheritance in c#. Now my problem is that what will i put in the question mark and in the if statement to know that the program passed a Person class or an Animal class or any class under InventoryApplication namespace. :)

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Logic_Layer.Logic logic = new Logic();
     //logic.Add<Person>();
}

namespace Logic_Layer
{

    public class Logic
    {
        public void Add<InventoryApplication>() where InventoryApplication : ?
        {
            //if { }
        }

        public void delete() { }
        public void edit() { }
        public void search() { }
        public void searchAll() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Namespaces are a way to organize classes, they play no role in inheritance so this will never work. A solution might be to have your common classes implement the same interface.

Comment: Oh my. i need to research more about this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use such a statement in the constraint. However, later in the method you can do this:

```
if (typeof(myObject).Namespace == "InventoryApplication")
{
...
}
```

What would be better is if the classes you want to test for (Animal, Person etc.) would implement an interface (say, `IMyInterface`).

For example:

```
 void Add<T>(<T> param) where T : IMyInterface {/*...*/}
```

Comment: how about in the question mark sir? what will i put?